# Date not working in Javascript setHours method

Tags: javascript, date

I am using javascript to insert events to my google calendar.

What I wanted to do was: 
If the time now is less than 15 minutes, it would set up the minutes to 00; if the time is more than 45 minutes, it would increase one hour and set up the minutes to 00 and if the time was between 15 and 45 minutes, it would set up the minutes to 30.

For example: if the time is now 11:25, it would be in the calendar 11:30. If the time was 11:10, it would put on the calendar 11:00 and if it was 11:50 it would add 12:00. However, the code is not working. Why?

The error that appears is: 
`POST https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json 400 (OK)`

```
                var eventstart = new Date();
                if (eventstart.getMinutes() < 15) {                     
                    eventstart.setMinutes(00);
                } else if (eventstart.getMinutes() > 45){
                    eventstart.setHours(eventstart.getHours()+1);
                    eventstart.setMinutes(00);
                } else {
                    eventstart.setMinutes(30);
                }
```

Comment: not working in what way? looks like it does exactly what you are telling it to do

Comment: The erro that shows is: POST https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json 400 (OK)

Comment: the code you posted has nothing to do with that

Comment: Can you post the code where you use the google calendar API to do the POST? It will most likely be executed before this code. Any include scripts or libraries you are using are important as well.